# Including a link in a <p> tag that sources its content from JSON in Svelte

Tags: javascript, html, json, svelte

I am new to Svelte and Sapper and I'm using it for my new project. A part of the implementation involves making multiple cards for which I declared data in JSON in the  section and then used iterations to create the multiple cards.

I need to include a link inside a paragraph and I cannot find a workaround. To put it into perspective, my code essentially looks like like this -

```
<script>
   let cards = [
      {
         paragraphText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
      },
      {
         paragraphText: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. This is where my link goes <a href="xyz.com">HYPERLINK</a>"
      }

   ]
</script>

{#each cards as card}
   <div class="card">
      <p>{card.paragraphText}</p> <!-- This is the paragraph that contains a hyperlink anchor tag inside it -->
   </div>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [@html](https://svelte.dev/docs#html) helper for rendering HTML content:

```
{#each cards as card}
   <div class="card">
      <p>{@html card.paragraphText}</p> <!-- This is the paragraph that contains a hyperlink anchor tag inside it -->
   </div>
{/each}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. I'll try it out right now

Comment: Alright! Make sure to mark it as an answer.